# The relation between two functions $\beta$ and $\alpha$ is: $\beta(\alpha(x))=\alpha(x)$. what is this problem?

Tags: optimization, fixed-point-theorems

I have $\beta(\alpha(x))=\alpha(x)$, where $x$ is any real number, and function $\beta$ can be computed if   value   $\alpha(x)$ is given.  I have also proved that function $\alpha$ is monotone with respect to $x$ and $\alpha(x)\in[0,1]$.

I want to obtain a mapping $\alpha$ (or an algorithm).
Is this a fixed-point problem? How to solve it, either mathematically or by algorithm?

---

Original problem explained:

The above problem comes from an economic and market scenario.
We have a function $$\psi(v_i)=v_i-\frac{G(v_i)-F(v_i)}{f(v_i)},$$ where the random variable $v_i$ is any real number (e.g.,  person $i$'s money). For any person $i$, his money $v_i$ is iid. $F(v)$ and $f(v)$ are the given cumulative distribution function (CDF) and probability density function (PDF) of  $v_i$, respectively. However, we don't know the form of $G(v_i)$, we only know that $G(v_i)\ge 1$.

We want to select a person $i^*$ who has the largest $ \psi(v_i)$ comparing with any other person. And more importantly, we also want that the probability that this person $i^*$ has the largest $\psi(v_i)$ should equal to the probability $\frac{1}{G(v_i)}$.

Briefly, **we want to find a function $G(v_i)$** such that when we select the largest $\psi(v_i)=v_i-\frac{G(v_i)-F(v_i)}{f(v_i)}$, the maximizer (i.e., person $i^*$)  are selected with a probability $\frac{1}{G(v_i)}$. This seems to be a fixed-point problem, so I summarize it into the following style
$$
      \mathbb{P}\big[{\psi}(G(v_i))\big]= \frac{1}{G(v_i)}.
$$
But I'm not sure whether this is correct and how to continue for the computation of $G(v_i)$.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You should provide more details, otherwise it is too vague.

Comment: Can you edit your post and mention clearly what are we looking for , are we solving for $F(x)$ in that case it would be easy but I'm not sure what we are solving for.